# Multiple domains with one google analytics account

Tags: google-analytics, multiple-domains

We developed a Magento website for a client which has 3 stores, and each store has 1 domain name, for example:

- Store 1 has `store1.com`
- Store 2 has `store2.com`
- Store 3 has `store3.com`

Our client wants to integrate Google Analytics on this 3 stores, the thing is that they want to track the 3 store separately from 1 single GA account.

From what i understand we can use the same GA account and use `_setDomainName('yourDomainName')` for each store/domain, this will give us report under the same GA account.

I am limited in my understanding, can someone help me confirm or tell me how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When logged onto Google Analytics, go to the Admin page. In the middle column under PROPERTY, click the drop down box and click Create New Property at the bottom.

This will allow you to add a new website/domain and track it from within your account.

Comment: it cannot be done without using property? what we want is track the stores differently under one account, using the property will allow us to have this structure? thanks for your response, i appreciate it.

Comment: That's correct. You can add the different stores as I have mentioned above. Then when you log on to Google Analytics you will see on your Dashboard the different sites listed in a column. You can see them all in an overview or click on each one to see more granular info.